# Splitting table in multiple pages in Elsevier journal format (elsarticle.cls)

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, tabularx, xtable

I am not able to accommodate my table in Elsevier journal manuscript format, so I need to split the table. Since the table has too many columns I rotate the table 90 degree(anticlockwise). And also having trouble in the caption. Here is my sample code for reference. Please help me out.Thank you in advance.

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}


\begin{document}

\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
%\captionsetup{font=footnotesize}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%\captionset
\label{table1}
\centering
\caption{Example Table 1}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.35cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}|}
\hline
A &B&C&D&E&F & G & H&I &J&K&L\\\hline
1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&910 &11&12&13\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline 
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic: You really shouldn't be loading both the `subfig` and the `caption` packages. Use one or the other, *but not both*.

Comment: Also, `\fontsize{11}{9}` almost certainly is an error. Were you thinking of writing `\fontsize{9}{11}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two choice:

- use `longtable` in `landscape` environment (see MWE below),
- manually split your table into two parts and each parts rotate

In the first case the MWE could be:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{array, longtable, tabularx}% added long table
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\modulolinenumbers[5]
\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\usepackage{pdflscape}% added
\usepackage{hyperref}% had to be last in preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\fontsize{11}{9}\selectfont
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\centering
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                |>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.35cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}
                 >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.1cm}|}
\caption{Example Table 1}
\label{table1}\\
    \hline
A & B & C & D & E & F & G & H & I & J  & K  & L     \\\hline
\endhead
\multicolumn{12}{r}{\footnotesize Continue on the next page}%?
\endfoot
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12    \\\hline
  &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &    &    &       \\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
&&&&&&&&&&&\\\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Note: landscape environment always star on the new page and occupy whole page.